# Problems using Node.js and multer to upload a zipped file and save it to MySql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, filesystems, multer

I am using Node.js and multer to upload a zipped file and save it to MySql database. I have succeeded in creating a login function whereby users can register, login, maintain a session key, and all is saved to the MySql DB.

When I try to upload the zip file and post it to my route and query it to the database, it doesnt work and says the upload object is undefined.

EDIT: 
The zipped file uploads and saves to the /upload folder as defined in the storage path in the multer function I added below, so it is working that far. I believe the problem could be in the post request in the JS code above the upload form, and/or in the async function.

EDIT:

//this is the error I receive, however i do not believe there is an issue with the db query itself, I believe it's an issue with the req.body object defined in the async function.

```
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage:
   'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'\'undefined\', \'undefined\', \'undefined\'\' at line 1',
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql:
   'INSERT into user_v_file (user_vile,vile_name,vile_desc) VALUES \'undefined\', \'undefined\', \'undefined\'' }
```

//This is the upload form and post request:

> ```
> <script>
> $(document).ready(function() {
>   $("#upload").click(function() {
>     $("#form-upload").toggle();
>     });
>     $('#uploadVr').click(function(e){
>         $.post("http://localhost:3000/upload",{
>                     user_vile : $("#uservile").val(),
>                     vile_name : $("#vilename").val(),
>                     vile_desc : $("#viledesc").val()
>                     },function(data){
>                 if(!data.error) {
>                     window.location.href = "/home";
>                 } else {
>                     alert(data.message);
>                 }
>             });
>         })
> });
> </script>
> </head>
> <body>
>     <button type="button" id="upload" value="Upload">Upload</button>
>     <button onclick="window.location.href='/home.html'" type="button" id="explore" value="Explore">Explore</button>
>
>     <form id="form-upload" action="/upload"  method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display:none">
>         Upload folder: <input type="file" id="uservile" name="vr_files">
>         VR name: <input type="text" id="vilename">
>         VR description: <input type="text" id="viledesc">
>         <input type="submit" id="uploadVr " value="Uploadfiles"/>
>     </form>
> </body>
> ```

```
// this is async function
```

> ```
> const upload = async (req, res) => {
>   try {
>     const {vile_name, vile_desc} = req.body;
>     const {user_vile} = req.file;
>     const resp = await db.upload(user_vile, vile_name, vile_desc); //should it be vr_file..?
>     req.session.key = resp;
>     res.send({error: false, message: "Vile added"});
>
>   } catch (e) {
>     res.send({error: true, message: "Vile upload failed"})
>     console.log(e);
>   }
>   console.log(req.body);
>   };
> ```

```
//this is the multer function to define upload storage path
```

> ```
> var storagePath = multer.diskStorage({
>     destination: function (req, file, cb) {
>       cb(null, './files/uploads')
>     },
>     filename: function (req, file, cb) {
>       cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
>     }
>   })
> var upload = multer({storage: storagePath})
> ```

```
// this is the route
```

`router.post('/upload', upload.single('user_vile'), main.upload);`

```
//this is the DB query


const upload = async (user_vile, vile_name, vile_desc) => {
  const results = await testDb.query(`INSERT into user_v_file (user_vile,vile_name,vile_desc) VALUES '${user_vile}', '${vile_name}', '${vile_desc}'`);
  return results
};
```

Comment: *doesn't work* is quite vague. What exactly doesn't work? Does the request arrive at the backend at all? Can you sucessfully post using another client, e.g. postman (or in other words: Is the error on the clientside)? So you get any errors?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question to better explain and added the error message and multer storage definition.

Answer (score 1):

All inputs need to have a name, however multiple of the inputs (namely the ones that arrive with `undefined` at the server) don't have one:

```
 <input type="text" id="vilename" name="vile_name" />
```

Yes, you do have a jQuery handler that tries to intercept the form post, and that makes an AJAX post request instead with the correct format, *however* that AJAX request will never run, as you do not cancel the form submit. To do so, call `e.preventDefault()` in the click handler.

And please make sure to prevent these [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection). You are really creating a security risk with your current code.

Comment: I've just updated my async function. Now, when I console.log(req.body) it logs the values from the two text inputs from the form, so it's just the zipped file it cannot read. If you'd like to call it a day that's fine you have helped me out a lot!

Comment: Yeah, the file will be on `req.files` not on `req.body` (if I understand the multer docs correctly)

Comment: Yeah it now says "TypeError: Cannot destructure property `user_vile` of 'undefined' or 'null'."..

Thank you for trying!!